# IntelliJ 2019.2 Services tool window missing

Tags: intellij-idea

I just updated to IntelliJ 2019.2 but I can't find the new Services tool window (described [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/08/services-tool-window-one-place-to-rule-them-all/)). Neither View - Tool Windows - Services nor `Alt + 8` is showing it. What am I missing?

Additional Information:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 (Ultimate Edition)
>   Build #IU-192.5728.98, built on July 23, 2019
>   Runtime version: 11.0.3+12-b304.10 amd64
>   VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>   Windows 7 6.1

Comment: What happens when you search for "Services" using the Strg + a shortcut (Search for Action). Is it listed there?

Comment: @Sebastian It's not listed in Search for Action

Comment: Ok, that's really strange. I can verify that it is there on macOS. Might be bug in the Windows version. Did you try the Java 8 runtime version?

Comment: when you look in the key map for "tool windows -> services" you can see which shortcut is assigned. In my case, (using the default OS X keymap) it seems there was no shortcut assigned, so I assigned one myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tool window automatically pops up when you run something related to a managed service (for example, run a Docker container). However, in case of run/debug configurations, you have to specify which types you want to be available in the Services tool window. For this, go to Run | Edit Configurations, select Templates, and add necessary configuration types to the Configurations available in Services list: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/08/services-tool-window-one-place-to-rule-them-all/

Comment: Yeah you are right.. actually the website I linked in my question gives the answer already, haha